# Unable to detect completion of TTS (callback) android.

Tags: android, callback, text-to-speech

I am developing android application in which I am using text to speech conversion.What I need when I open my application run text to speech conversion. After completion of this I want to do some thing.My code looks like

```
public class Mainactivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener, OnUtteranceCompletedListener{
    private static int REQ_CODE = 1;
    private TextToSpeech tts = null;
    private boolean ttsIsInit = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    startTextToSpeech();
    }

    private void startTextToSpeech() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQ_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this); 
            } 
            else {
                Intent installVoice = new Intent(Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installVoice);
            }
        }
    }

        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                ttsIsInit = true;
                int result = tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
                if (tts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.ENGLISH) >= 0)
                    tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                tts.setPitch(5.0f);
                tts.setSpeechRate(1.0f);

                 HashMap<String, String> myHashAlarm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                  myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM));
                  myHashAlarm.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "SOME MESSAGE");
                  tts.speak("hi how are you?", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashAlarm);
             }
        }

   @Override
   public void onDestroy() {
      if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
      }
        super.onDestroy();
     }

   @Override
   public void onUtteranceCompleted(String uttId) {
       Toast.makeText(Mainactivity.this,"done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       if (uttId.equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
           Toast.makeText(Mainactivity.this,"inside done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       } 
   }
}
```

When I open my application text to speech working fine. But how to detect whether text to speech completed or not.Need help..... Thank you.....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using API level 15 or later you can set a progress listener on your `TextToSpeech` reference using

```
setOnUtteranceProgressListener(UtteranceProgressListener listener)
```

You will get callbacks reporting the progress of the TTS, including a callback when it is finished. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/UtteranceProgressListener.html

However, I notice that you're already using the deprecated `OnUtteranceCompletedListener`. Are you getting the callbacks on `onUtteranceCompleted()`? That should also work.

Comment: Hi david I tried you solution but it gives me error for setOnUtteranceProgressListener.And for onUtteranceCompleted it executes without an error but not giving message in onUtteranceCompleted so is there way to solve this problem. Whether I am doing any thing wrong.Need Help...

Comment: You call `int result = tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(thi s);` to set the listener. Check the value of the `result` variable. SUCCESS (0) or ERROR (-1) should come back. Also, add some logging to `onUtteranceCompleted()` to see if it actually gets there. Also check your logcat for any other strange errors.

Comment: Thank you david thank you for response. Its working fine.I use logging instead of toast and its working fine. Thank you...

Answer (score 8):

Call the setOnUtteranceCompletedListener inside the onInit function of the tts object.

If you want to make any changes to the UI on the call of the onUtteranceCompleted function, add the code inside a runOnUIThread method.

And do remember to add the Hashmap param value while calling the speak() function

Example :

```
TextToSpeech tts= new TextToSpeech(context, new OnInitListener() {

 @Override
 public void onInit(int status) {

    mTts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                //UI changes
                }
            });
        }
    });

 }
});


HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,"stringId");

tts.speak("Text to Speak",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is some code from [here](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/SpeechRecognizingAndSpeakingActivity.java) that helps you be backward compatible so you don't have to target 15.

```
private void setTtsListener()
    {
        final SpeechRecognizingAndSpeakingActivity callWithResult = this;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 15)
        {
            int listenerResult = tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDone(String utteranceId)
                {
                    callWithResult.onDone(utteranceId);
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String utteranceId)
                {
                    callWithResult.onError(utteranceId);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStart(String utteranceId)
                {
                    callWithResult.onStart(utteranceId);
                }
            });
            if (listenerResult != TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "failed to add utterance progress listener");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int listenerResult = tts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId)
                {
                    callWithResult.onDone(utteranceId);
                }
            });
            if (listenerResult != TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "failed to add utterance completed listener");
            }
        }
    }
```